# What is the *nix parallel to Microsoft front page (HTML page builder)?

Tags: gui, software-rec, html, javascript, documents

Just as LibreOffice is the current parallel to Microsoft Office and just as GIMP is the current parallel to Adobe Photoshop, what is the *nix parallel to Microsoft front page (HTML page builder)?

Can I use some LibreOffice tool for to create HTML pages in which JavaScript and/or CSS are saved **inline** or **indocument**)?

### Update

Preferably, something with a "drag and drop" mechanics but not necessarily.
AFAIK, WYSIWIG lacks drag and drop mechanics (such as those of Gutenberg/Elementor).

Comment: https://documentation.libreoffice.org/assets/Uploads/Documentation/en/GS5.1/HTML/GS5112-CreatingWebPages.html

Comment: https://books.libreoffice.org/en/GS71/GS7112-CreatingHTMLFiles.html#toc20

Answer (score 1):

I honestly think Frontpage is a bit of a thing of the past; matter of fact, it's been discontinued for 19 years (!!); nowadays, most HTML [WYSIWIG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editing happens in-browser (exactly what happens when you go to e.g. your Gmail account and make a word **bold** in your email, or you go to your wordpress site and write an article, or click on the (by now default) editor on wikipedia pages; if you want to have such an editor yourself, [here's](https://quilljs.com/playground/) an example of one in action).

On larger sites / professional sites, the way the visible content is composed to look like it does to you is really not representable by a static editor like FrontPage used to be. (The concept of responsive layout, dynamically fetched information, and reactive content simply is incompatible with the idea of HTML being the full representation of the page.)

However, I'm sure there's still a good reason d'etre for WYSIWIG HTML editors. A more modern variant is [BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/); but there's so many, wikipedia has [an article comparing them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_editors#Operating_system_support)¹.

---

¹ subliminal message: maybe asking here isn't the fastest way to find software if there's so much information out there!

Answer (score -2):

What you are looking for is a WYSIWYG editor. After a websearch, I came across [kompozer](https://kompozer.net/) through multiple sources.

Haven't used it myself, but hope it helps.

Comment: Kompozer is discontinued and hasn't seen a release in nearly 15 years; it won't do with modern HTML5. That's not a great recommendation!

Comment: If anything from that family, you'd recommend the Seamonkey "Composer" editor component, which is not as dead, but honestly, still pretty much a terrible HTML editor (sorry, mozilla) and terribly dated.